# Передача динамического массива в функцию

Tags: массивы, pascal, freepascal

Возможно ли передать в функцию два двумерных динамических массива в FreePascal?
По Форумам ползал- ничего толкового не нашел.

```
var m,n,k:integer;
mass1: array of array of real;
mass2: array of array of real;

begin
setlength(mass1,m,n);
setlength(mass2,n,k);
//Вот этот блок нужно как-то запихать в подпрограмму (задача стоит такая)
for i:=0 to m-1 do
        for j:=0 to k-1 do begin
        summ:=0;
        for l:=0 to n-1 do
        summ:=summ+mass1[i,l]*mass2[l,j];
        mass3[i,j]:=summ;
        end;
//конец блока

readln();
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type
  TArrayOfArrayOfReal = array of array of Real;
procedure DoSomething(var A, B: TArrayOfArrayOfReal);
var
  I, J, L: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(A) do
    for J := 0 to High(B[0]) do
      ...
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!